# How to rotate Viewport (not object, not camera) around Z axis

Tags: 3d-view

How to rotate Viewport (not object, not camera) around the Z axis only. is there another way to rotate the viewport horizontally beside Numpad 6. the view can be easily rotate to above or below the the object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, as far as I know only `Numpad 4` and `Numpad 6` can be used to rotate along Z axis. What do you mean by "the view can be easily rotate to above or below the the object"?

Comment: Yes. You can use a Camera for Viewing. Parent the camera to an Empty centered in the world's origin. Now you can rotate the empty along its Z axis and the Camera will follow.

Comment: @RumenBelev It is stated clearly in the question to rotate the viewport and **not** a camera.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The viewport is not rotated, you just see through a camera that is not visible or selectable - the question is misleading and my answer is still a valid alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Fly Navigation` with `Shift` + `~` or `View` > `Navigation` > `Fly Navigation`.

Here is an addon.

[image]

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Viewport Euler Rotation",
    "author": "unwave",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "View3D > N-Panel > View",
    "description": "More viewport controls. A kind of a hack",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
}


import bpy
import mathutils


KEYS = set(bpy.types.RegionView3D.bl_rna.properties.keys())

NOT_USEFUL = {
    'clip_planes',
    'is_orthographic_side_view',
    'is_perspective',
    'perspective_matrix',
    'rna_type',
    'use_box_clip',
    'use_clip_planes',
    'view_matrix',
    'window_matrix',
}

class VIEWPORTEULER_PT_viewport_properties(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "TEST_PT_viewport_properties"
    bl_label = "Viewport Euler Rotation"
    bl_category = "View"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        column = self.layout.column(align=True)

        column.prop(context.window_manager, 'viewporteuler_viewport_rotation')

        region_3d = context.space_data.region_3d
        for attr in dir(region_3d):
            if attr.startswith('_'):
                continue
            if not attr in KEYS:
                continue
            if attr in NOT_USEFUL:
                continue
            column.prop(context.space_data.region_3d, attr)

        column.prop(context.window_manager, 'viewporteuler_live_update')

view_rotation_euler = mathutils.Euler((0, 0, 0), 'XYZ')
PI_x_2 = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884 * 2


def get_view_rotation_euler(self):
    global view_rotation_euler
    region_3d = bpy.context.area.spaces.active.region_3d

    return region_3d.view_rotation.to_euler('XYZ', view_rotation_euler)

def set_view_rotation_euler(self, value):
    global view_rotation_euler
    region_3d = bpy.context.area.spaces.active.region_3d

    euler = mathutils.Euler(value, 'XYZ')

    quaternion = euler.to_quaternion()
    quaternion.make_compatible(region_3d.view_rotation)

    region_3d.view_rotation = quaternion

    view_rotation_euler = mathutils.Euler((n % PI_x_2 for n in quaternion.to_euler('XYZ', view_rotation_euler)), 'XYZ')


def update_side_panel_callback():
    for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
        if region.type == 'UI':
            region.tag_redraw()


drawing_handler = None

def get_live_update(self):
    global drawing_handler

    return bool(drawing_handler)

def set_live_update(self, value):
    global drawing_handler

    if drawing_handler is not None:
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(drawing_handler, 'WINDOW')

    if value:
        drawing_handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(update_side_panel_callback, tuple(), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
    else:
        drawing_handler = None


def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.viewporteuler_viewport_rotation = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(name='Viewport Rotation', step=6, subtype='EULER', get=get_view_rotation_euler, set=set_view_rotation_euler)

    bpy.types.WindowManager.viewporteuler_live_update = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='Live Update Hack', get=get_live_update, set=set_live_update)

    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEWPORTEULER_PT_viewport_properties)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEWPORTEULER_PT_viewport_properties)

    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, 'viewporteuler_live_update')

    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, 'viewporteuler_viewport_rotation')

    set_live_update(None, False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Really good looking addon code, thanks for this cool contribution. Instead of defining PI_x_2 yourself you could also use the existing math library [`math.tau`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_tau.asp).